# Is it okay to say that "part-author" is synonymous with "co-author"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is it okay to say that "part-author" is synonymous with "co-author"? If not, how are they different?

"George Peele has often been proposed as a possible part-author of Shakespeare's Titus Andronicus."

Comment: part-author simply does not work.

Comment: When you invent a term, you have to educate your reader first as to why you need the term. Actually, why do you need the term? Maybe Peele was a minor-part author? Since co-author sounds like writers worked together, maybe you want to say that was not the case -- but some other arrangement?

Comment: part does not take a hyphen in English: part human,part bird, part lion. Guess what it is? part is an adjective and if a noun, it means something else: a part you play or act.

Comment: @Lambie - But I think part- is a prefix here. For example, the part-owner of a restaurant.

Comment: "Part-author" suggests that George Peele wrote some of the scenes, WS wrote the others. I suggest [**collaborator**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/collaborator): A person who works jointly on an activity or project; an associate.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Then you think it's synonymous with co-author, don't you?

Comment: Collaborator: yes. Part-author: no. There is also ambiguity in 'part-author' on two counts, a) Peele wrote the lines for specific characters (and perhaps that was the case), b) Peele was part author, part blacksmith or some other trade.

Comment: ""Part-author" suggests that George Peele wrote some of the scenes, WS wrote the others." But co-author means the same!

Comment: Not necessarily. They might have conferred continually, but only one of them (or a clerk) actually wrote anything. They wrote by hand, so it would have been obvious.

Comment: Why make up a new word that people will only guess at your intention, when you can just use 'co-author'?

Comment: @NIck08 part-novelist part-screenwriter = same person. He is part-author part-engineer. The same person. You can't be "part-x with someone else" when it comes to writing.

Comment: @Mitch - I'm not making up a new word! Search the Google Books for "part-author" and you can find numerous examples.

Comment: @NIck08 It's a pretty rare word then. You said 'define' so I figured you're making it up. This should give you a string indication that you shouldn't try to use it as a synonym of 'co-author'. If you mean 'co-author' then use that. If you mean something slightly different, then maybe 'part-author' but you'd certainly need to clarify nearby if you use it.

Comment: I would understand "co-author" as meaning someone who had a very similar input to the work as the other author - compare - *co-star* and *co-director.* For someone who has a lesser input, I would call them a *contributing author*